# How reliable is a bootable linux flash drive?

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to create a bootable linux flash drive. I want to find out how reliable and effective it is. Does it work like linux operating system installed on a laptop. I probably will be using the flash drive for linux related task that probably won't work on a ms-windows operating system.

Comment: Flash drives have a more limited number of writes and are a lot slower on writes. I can do a full install of Ubuntu to USB3 flash drive in an hour, but only 10 minutes to external SSD on USB3 port. But once program is in RAM it does not matter where it loaded from, same speed. SSD life is now comparable to HDD, but all systems require good backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is inside or outside of the computer. Being inside seems magical. However no magical powers are granted. The other difference is how is is connected USB or SATA. All of this can effect speed, depending on the version of USB and SATA.

There are a few machines that will not boot from USB (probably hard to find, as this is needed to install a new system).

The USB storage device may were out quicker than the internal device (but this all depends on the device). Almost all SSD devices have a limited number of write operations. But this only applies if the USB storage is SSD (May be you are using a hard disk).

Externally connected devices are more susceptible to physical problems: e.g. being unplugged.

If you are using it a lot with the same machine, and not using the internal storage. Then it is probably worth installing to this internal storage. You can use `gparted` to shrink MS-Windows partition, and create a new partition for your Gnu/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Chinelo.

A bootable flash drive is used to try how the Linux works on your computer and everything is fine. The Booting is slow. It works like a Linux System installed but the work you did with it won't be saved into the hard disk. But you can use persistence option. Many people don't know about it.

https://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/